# Operator overloading - Index does not print

Tags: c++

I have coursework to generate the Game of Life using C++, and must follow the instructions of the lecturer in order to pass. The state of the board is stored in a std::vector. A helper index function which takes in an x and y position is required to get the 1D position in the vector. 2 operator overloaded classes are required, 1 (the non const) to overwrite the value in the vector, and the other (the const) to print the value in the vector. Here are the classes so far:

The code below compiles.

In the main class, setting a grid value works OK e.g. grid(6,1) = 1.
Printing the value of the cell at a specific grid does not print the value.

I'm unsure whether the cause of the problem is the operator overload functions, or is it the ostream operator<< overload.

In the main class, I dropped a break point on this line:

```
std::cout << "(6, 1) = " <<  grid(6,1) << std::endl;
```

When evaluating the value of grid(6,1) when debugging, the content is 1, so this leads me to suspect that maybe my overloaded ostream is not programmed correctly.

World.h file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class World {

private:
    int width, height, timestep;
    std::vector<char> currentCells, nextCells;
    size_t index(int x, int y) const;

public:
    World(int width, int height);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const World &rhs);
    friend std::ostream& headerLine(std::ostream &os, const World &rhs);

    char & operator()(int x, int y);
    const char& operator()(int x, int y) const;
};
```

World.cpp file:

```
#include "World.h"

World::World(int _width, int _height) : width(_width), height(_height), timestep(0),
                currentCells(_width * _height, ' '), nextCells(_width * _height) {}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const World &rhs) {

    os << "timestep " << rhs.timestep << "\n";

    headerLine(os, rhs);
    for (auto i = 0; i < rhs.height; i++) {
        os << "|";
        for (auto j = 0; j < rhs.width; j++) {
            if (rhs.currentCells[j + (i * rhs.width)] == ' ') {
                os << ' ';
            } else {
                os << '0';
            }
        }
        os << "|\n";
    }
    headerLine(os, rhs);
    return os;
}

std::ostream& headerLine(std::ostream& os, const World &rhs) {
    os << "+";
    for (auto i = 0; i < rhs.width; i++) {
        os << "-";
    }
    os << "+\n";
    return os;
}

size_t World::index(int x, int y) const{
    return y * width + x;
}

char& World::operator()(int x, int y) {
    return currentCells[index(x, y)];
}

const char& World::operator()(int x, int y) const {
    return currentCells[index(x,y)];
}
```

main class file:

```
#include "World.h"

int main() {
    World grid(10,5);

    grid(6,1) = 1;
    grid(5,1) = 1;

    std::cout << grid << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(6, 1) = " <<  grid(6,1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output on the console:

`(6, 1) = 1`

Actual output on the console:

`(6, 1) =`

Comment: It seems `grid()` returns char which is whitespace, you need to promote it to `int` to see decimal value.

Comment: Sidenote: your `index` function is declared as `char index(int x, int y) const;`, while being defined as `size_t World::index(int x, int y) const`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius just updated the code now 

Comment: @rafix07 Perfect, this solved the printing issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These two overloaded operators:

```
char& World::operator()(int x, int y) {
    return currentCells[index(x, y)];
}

const char& World::operator()(int x, int y) const {
    return currentCells[index(x,y)];
}
```

Are returning either a `char&` or a `const char&` and when you use it within a `cout` statement as you have done:

```
std::cout << "(6, 1) = " <<  grid(6,1) << std::endl;
```

It is either going to print some character based on the architecture and OS of your machine. It may be an ASCII printable or non printable character, you may even hear a beep coming from your internal buzzer speaker, or it could be from some other encoded character format besides ASCII.

As others have stated in the comments you need to promote this to an `int` type. The easiest way to do this is by doing the following:

```
std::cout << "(6, 1) = " << +grid(6,1) << std::endl;
```

All I did here was add a `+` before the `operator` call. This is unary addition and will promote a `char` type to `int` type.